# SPF Records with Subdomains

Tags: spf, amazon-ses

Amazon recommends the following SPF Record:

```
"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com -all"
```

However, will this work for SES servers based in EU?

> eu-west-1.amazonses.com

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Otherwise I see the following in Gmail: Sent via eu-west-1.amazonses.com

Comment: So? What is your _actual_ problem?

Comment: I dont want to see "via eu-west-1.amazonses.com". https://support.google.com/mail/answer/1311182?hl=en-GB&ctx=mail

Comment: Then you should do what Google recommends, and set up your SPF and DKIM.

Comment: Yes...that's the whole point of my question. Amazon recommends the SPF record above but I don't know if that works for subdomains. I have set up the records but still have the same issue.

Comment: I've also verified it with several SPF verification services like check-auth@verifier.port25.com

Comment: You could make the change you propose, but it wouldn't solve your problem. That's the point. You should ask about your actual problem, rather than [going off on tangents](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/189912) like this.

Comment: How am I going off on a tangent? My question is simple...will the above SPF record cover subdomains of amazonses.com.

Comment: Did you click the link and _read it_?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. Its a simple question about how SPF records work with SES.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The records at `eu-west-1.amazonses.com` are the following:

```
eu-west-1.amazonses.com. 900    IN      TXT     "spf2.0/pra include:amazonses.com -all"
eu-west-1.amazonses.com. 900    IN      TXT     "v=spf1 include:amazonses.com -all"
```

Which means that including `eu-west-1.amazonses.com` instead of `amazonses.com` doesn't make any difference to the end result other than adding an extra lookup.

Also, setting up SPF as the service instructs you to would appear to be the safe bet in case they change their records later on (not necessarily taking into account that someone may have come up with alternative solutions).